Property 'newContext' does not exist on type 'APIRequestContext'
I'm  using  playwright with TypeScript:
  // Create a new API context with the retrieved token
  
   apiContext = await request.newContext({
    extraHTTPHeaders: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
  });
});

To solve the problem:

Property 'newContext' does not exist on type 'APIRequestContext'.


Where did you get from that APIRequestContext has a newContext function?

Should be possible according to the documentation: https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-apirequest. Looks like the used request  variable is the APIRequestContext instead of the APIRequest.

Please show your full code. As mentioned, it looks like request is misleadingly named, and already is the context.
